# Открыть несколько табов по одному клику Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, браузер

Вопрос таков - хоть какими-нибудь хаками возможно это сделать?
У меня пользователи выбирают список линков и по клику они должны разом открываться в новых табах.

Бьюсь в поисках уже несколько дней. Пробовал создавать ссылки by js, window.open(), фейковые клики, атрибуты, 2 либы и ничего...

И конечно же имеется ввиду обход блокировки всплывающих окон.

Спасибо.

Comment: А где это вы видели обход блокировки всплывающих окон?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs `chrome.tabs.create(object createProperties, function callback)`

Comment: @Cheg, нет, не видел. Поэтому и задаю вопрос, возможно ли.

Comment: @Aid , это же сайт, а не расширение для гугла. В эту сторону уже тоже смотрел. Но спасибо за попытку))

Comment: @OlegReym отменить блокировку может только пользователь. Без его вмешательства вы этого не сделаете

Comment: Тогда никак. Специально систему защиты ввели, был когда-то в тёмные времена наплыв спаммеров, за это отдуваемся.

Comment: Oleg Reim, есть вариант одного охренительного по своей реализации хака. Но это именно хак, который плюс надо будет очень и очень аккуратно написать чтоб он был безопасен. Могу кинуть в ответ, но я предупредил. Надо?)

Comment: Надо понимать, что если вы сейчас найдете хак и он будет работать, завтра это исправят и он не будет работать. Я бы не советовал тратить много сил и времени на сомнительные решения. В данном случае можно сделать уведомление типа "Для корректной работы с сайтом необходимо добавить его в исключения всплывающих окон" или что то типа того, как делают на сайтах уведомления о Куках и тд.

Comment: @Skywave в какой-то степени вы правы, но для меня этот вопрос все же актуален.

Comment: @Vyacheslav Potseluyko так а почему еще не кинул?))) Я готов)))

Comment: @OlegReym, ошибся. Идея была устроить у себя xxs дыру. С ключом безопасности и какими-то ограничениями. А дальше рекурсивно через неё передавать код. Но это вам не поможет, извините. Ошибся..

Comment: Привет.
А как на счет отправки пользователя в fullscren, далее эмуляция браузера с вкладками? И открывай себе хоть миллион вкладок...

Answer (score 1):

Для выполнения `window.open()` необходимы условия:

1. Стек `trace` должен содержать доверенное событие. Формально, для инициирования такого события не обязательно нужен клик, тот же `mousemove` даёт доверенное событие не хуже `click`.

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = event=>console.log(event.isTrusted);
document.querySelector('button').onmousemove = event=>console.log(event.isTrusted);
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
```

2. Тут одно из двух: либо в браузере стоит добровольно вручную установленное пользователем  разрешение всплывающих окон. Либо среди заголовков `Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy` будет передан [`allow-popups`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/sandbox) или [`unsave-none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy). [Примеры можно взять отсюда](https://content-security-policy.com/). Если сервер принадлежит вам, то с этим проблем не должно возникнуть.

Answer (score 0):

Алерт с предупреждением не выскакивает, если к нему привели действия пользователя. Попробуйте таким образом.

```html
<form action="#">
    <button id="b1" type="submit" onclick="document.getElementById(`b2`).click()" formtarget="_blank">1</button>
    <button id="b2" type="submit" onclick="document.getElementById(`b1`).click()" formtarget="_blank">2</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -2):

Я думаю вам это подойдет:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>

        function o(){

            window.open('http://ya.ru');

        }
            function t(){

            window.open('http://yta.ru');

        }
            function f(){

            window.open('http://yfa.ru');

        }
           function p(){

        w=    window.open('#');
          if(!w) {alert('Внимание! Необходимо разрешить открытие всплывающих окон');}  
        } 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id=o onclick="o();">
            <div id=t onclick="t();">
                <div id=f onclick="f();" >
                    <p onclick="p();">text</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Извините, вы пробовали сами это? Вопрос читали? alert в коде с оповещением, что нужно разрешить всплывающие окна, говорит сам за себя, что это не ответ на поставленный вопрос. P.S. - код я проверил.

Comment: Обход блокировки окон нельзя обойти скриптом на сайте