# Открыть несколько вкладок в браузере

Tags: javascript, html5

На странице test.html есть :

```
<a href="/myfold/test_01.html" target="_blank">tst_1</a><br>
<a href="/myfold/test_02.html" target="_blank">tst_2</a><br>    
<a href="/myfold/test_03.html" target="_blank">tst_3</a><br>
```

Делаю на своем компе в хроме на localhost. 
По клику, - каждая открывается в новой вкладке. Хочу открыть все одним кликом и,
в идеале, остаться/вернуться на исходную test.html

---

Вешал на кнопку :

```
function openAll() {
   window.open("http://localhost/myfold/test_01.html");
   window.open("http://localhost/myfold/test_02.html");
   window.open("http://localhost/myfold/test_03.html"); 
}
```

Открывает только первую test_01.html
Ставил задержку через setTimeout ..., - не помогло.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно сделать?

Comment: Сдается мне что сейчас все браузеры не допускают открытие больше одного окна при одном клике, хотя может есть вариант обойти такую ситуацию.

Comment: да, похоже, что так сделано и не обойти

Comment: Похожее по теме : https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/700307/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83-chrome?rq=1

Comment: Пересмотрите концепцию проекта, значит надо обойтись без такого решения или же сделать несколько невидимых слоев каждый друг над другом и когда пользователь будет кликать по элементу, то каждый раз будет открываться новое окно, так часто делают на всяких видео хостингах.

Comment: Принцип такой: один клик - одно окно, обойти можно только если пользователь разрешит открытие окон с вашего ресурса.